# How to show the dimension of the vector space $K[X]/fK[X]?$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $f\neq 0 \in K[X]$ a polynomial.

a) Show that the Ring $K[X]/fK[X]$ is a $K$-vector space with the dimension $n=\deg(f)$

b) $f$ is called irreducible, if for $g,h \in K[X]$ we have $f=g*h \Rightarrow$ $\deg(g)=0 $ or $\deg(h)=0$

Show that $f$ is irreducible if and only if, $K[X]/fK[X]$ is a field

I don't think I have much difficulties to prove in a) that it is a vector space, and I am thinking of using the dimension formula : $ \dim U/V = \dim U - \dim V$ to prove the dimension but somehow I can only conclude $\dim K[X]/fK[X] = -\deg(f)$, which is not exactly what I am looking for. And I still don't have any idea on how to start b)

Comment: $K[x]$ is infinite dimensional as a $K$-vector space. You have to be careful about the dimension formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Part A

You should apply the chinese remainder theorem, and then consider the powers of $\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is the quotient map. Assume for simplicity that $f$ is irreducible: I claim that the first $0$ through $(k-1)$ powers form a linearly independent set, in this resulting quotient. But then what happens to the $n^{th}$ power? If $f(X)= c_kx^k +c_{k-1}x^{k-1} +...+c_0=0$ then $c_kx^k=-(c_{k-1}x^{k-1} +...+c_0)$, (here i've become lazy and just referred to the image of $x$ as $x$) which means you've written it as a linear combination of the elements I claimed formed a linearly independent set. In this fashion you can also reduce any power higher than $k$. So in fact that set forms a basis and has $k$ elements!

- Part B

If  $f$ is not irreducible, then what happens when you multiply the image of its factors under the quotient map? I claim you will have zero divisors.

Comment: Alright thank you for your answer, I think I now have a good answer for B, however I don't know at this point what the quotient map is... Could you please explain briefly what it is ?

Comment: The quotient map take a polynomial, to its value module $f(x)$. Another way to think about this is that it take a polynomial to its remainder when divided by $f(x)$

Comment: Oh that map ! I see, it is much clearer, thank you !